# Failed to patch object for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a class used to authenticate with google sheet API and retrieve data from some spreadsheets.
Here a part of it:

spreadsheet.py

```
from typing import Optional
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import gspread


class GoogleSheet:
    def __init__(self, token_file: str):
        self.token_file: str = token_file
        self.google_client: Optional[gspread.Client] = None
        self.gsheet: Optional[gspread.Spreadsheet] = None

    def setup_connection(self) -> None:
        credentials: Credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(self.token_file)
        if credentials.expired:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        self.google_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    def open_gsheet_by_url(self, gsheet_url: str) -> None:
        self.gsheet = self.google_client.open_by_url(gsheet_url)
```

I wanted to create some tests for the previous code.
Here is what I ended to:
test_spreadsheet.py

```
import pytest
from spreadsheet import GoogleSheet
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestSpreadSheetData:
    @patch('spreadsheet.Credentials')
    @patch('spreadsheet.gspread')
    def test_setup_connection(self, mocked_creds, mocked_auth):
        google_sheet = GoogleSheet('api_token.json')
        google_sheet.setup_connection()
        assert mocked_creds.from_authorized_user_file.call_count == 1
        assert mocked_auth.authorize.call_count == 1
```

I tried the code above but it didn't work although I had similar approach with different project and packages.
So whenever I run the test, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError
Assert 0 == 1
```

Can anyone helps me fix this?

Comment: You got your mocks in the wrong order. The nearest decorator is handled first, so you need `test_setup_connection(self, mocked_auth, mocked_creds)`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thank you so much. That works now!